# Ansible - math operation, substract

Tags: math, ansible

Trying to substract a number for a variable, which is an int in Ansible.

```
var:
  number: 30
tasks:
  - set_fact: me={{ number -1 }}
  - debug: var=me
```

Expectation: `me = 29`

Result:

```
 fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ number - 1 }}): unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'AnsibleUnicode' and 'int'"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known issue with Ansible/Jinja that you can't preserve numeric type after templating.

Use `int` filter inside `{{..}}` expression:

```
- set_fact: me={{ number | int - 1 }}
```